# How to change Ubuntu user email address

Tags: ubuntu-email-address

Two days ago, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 first time.

I have a slightly damaged keyboard and when I created the user, I typed the email address wrong.

Is there any possibility to change it?
Any ideas?

Comment: Eh. what email?  where did you type it? useradd has "Full Name, Phone, Home-Phone, and Other " Generally your login@host can be used as an email. If "Other" was used: see `/etc/passwd` but be careful altering that file :)

Comment: the command line method is `chfn`

Comment: email is generally handled in e.g. Thunderbird or any other email client. *In other contexts an email-address might be present, and possibly displayed, but usually not used for anything else.*